# Copying Binary Files

Tags: c

I'm trying to figure out how to copy binary files from one place to another .exe's. I can't seem to find any solutions to learn.

I'm using Windows. What's the best way to do it?

Comment: You should post anything you have tried, so we can get an idea of how to help - this is a pretty easy operation in most programming languages.

Answer (score 13):

**What do you mean "best way"?** I think this is the most straightforward way ... hopefully that is what you meant :)

---

`fopen` the input and output files with binary mode

```
FILE *exein, *exeout;

exein = fopen("filein.exe", "rb");
if (exein == NULL) {
    /* handle error */
    perror("file open for reading");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
exeout = fopen("fileout.exe", "wb");
if (exeout == NULL) {
    /* handle error */
    perror("file open for writing");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

`fread` and `fwrite`

```
size_t n, m;
unsigned char buff[8192];
do {
    n = fread(buff, 1, sizeof buff, exein);
    if (n) m = fwrite(buff, 1, n, exeout);
    else   m = 0;
} while ((n > 0) && (n == m));
if (m) perror("copy");
```

and finally close the files

```
if (fclose(exeout)) perror("close output file");
if (fclose(exein)) perror("close input file");
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you open the files with the O_BINARY option if you use `open()` and file descriptors, or with the letter "b" in the mode string if you use `fopen()`.  Note that O_BINARY is not standard except on Windows; however, you can treat it (or define it) as 0 on Unix and all will be fine.  If you are using a pure Windows API, then make sure you are doing the equivalent - make sure you specify that the file is treated as a binary file.

Comment: `open` is a POSIX function, and Windows is not POSIX.

Answer (score 2):

Windows has a [CopyFile API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (if you don't mind being platform specific). One thing to be careful of these days is making sure you have permissions to write to the destination area.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to copy Binary Files:

```
int get_file_size(char *source)
{
    FILE *fichier = fopen(source,"rb");
    fseek(fichier,0,SEEK_END);
    int size = ftell(fichier);
    fseek(fichier,0,SEEK_SET);
    fclose(fichier);
    return size;
}
void copy(char *source, char *dest)
{
    int srcsize = get_file_size(source);
    char *data = (char *)malloc(srcsize);
    int fsource = open(source,O_RDONLY | O_BINARY);
    int fdest = open(dest,O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_BINARY);
    read(fsource,data,srcsize);
    write(fdest,data,srcsize);
    close(fsource);
    close(fdest);
}
```

Comment: Many problems: Why split the code in 2 separate functions that use different APIs? Type `int` is inappropriate for a file size, (although in Microsoft Windows, `int` and `long` have the same size...) No test for `fopen()` or `open` failure. No test for `malloc()` failure. Missing 3rd argument to `open` with `O_CREAT` flag. No test on `read` nor `write`. No useful return value...

Answer (score -1):

You can use function of 'dos.h' for low-level IO operation.
Following code illustrate use of them. Hope it will helpful

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<dos.h>
#include<FCNTL.H>
#include<SYS\STAT.H>
void main()
{
    char s_file[100],d_file[100],buf[512];
    short char copy='y';
    int in_handle,out_handle,flg,len;
    printf("\nEnter File Name : ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(s_file);
    printf("\nEnter Destination File Name : ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(d_file);
    // open file for reading
    in_handle=open(s_file,O_RDONLY | O_BINARY);
    if(in_handle<0)
    {
        printf("\nSource File not Found... ");
    }
    else
    {
        // open file for writing
        out_handle=open(d_file,O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_BINARY,S_IWRITE);
        while((len=read(in_handle,buf,512))>0)
        {
            flg=write(out_handle,buf,len);
            if(flg==-1)
                break;
        }
        if(flg==-1)
        {
            printf("Unable to Create");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("File Created");
        }
    }
     if(!(in_handle<0))
        close(in_handle);
     if(!(out_handle<0));
        close(out_handle);
}
```

Comment: `S_IWRITE` is incorrect. you should also specify read and execute permissions.

Comment: DV because of `void main()`, `fflush(stdin);`, `gets(s_file);`, `gets(d_file);`. Furthermore `write(out_handle,buf,len);` could return a short count, indicating only a portion of `buf` was written. You only test for write error.

Answer (score -3):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
     FILE *fp1,*fp2;
     char c;
     fp1=fopen("source file","rb");
     if(fp1==NULL)
       exit(1);
     fp2=fopen("destination file","wb");
     if(fp2==NULL)
       exit(1);
     while((c=fgetc(fp1))!=EOF)
          fputc(c,fp2);
     fclose(fp1);
     fclose(fp2);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this might not be the *best* solution, it would at least be a correct solution if `c` was defined with type `int`.

Answer (score -4):

http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/file-io/intro/

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define BUFSIZE 1024

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
charmybuf[BUFSIZE] = { 0 }, *p = NULL;
FILE *ifd = NULL, *ofd = NULL;
ifp = fopen( argv[1], “r” );
ofp = fopen( argv[2], “w” );
assert(ifp!=NULL);
assert(ofp!=NULL);
while ( ( n = fread( mybuf, sizeof(char), BUFSIZE ,ifd) ) > 0 )
{
    fwrite(mybuf, sizeof(char),BUFSIZE,ofd);
}
fclose(ifd);
fclose(ofd);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Arrrgggg: smart quotes !!! whoever thought of calling them smart??? they're DUMB QUOTES ... and ... `sizeof(char)`, by definition, is `1`

Comment: What do you want `n` for? You never use it for anything.

Comment: Need to specify binary mode ("rb" and "wb") for this to work correctly on systems (like Windows) that distinguish between text & binary "FILE"s; and you're writing garbage if the file is not an exact multiple of BUFSIZE bytes.