# Error copying a file with different extensions in C

Tags: c

I'm new on stackoverflow ! I have a problem with my code. I would have liked to know how can I improve my code so that it copies all kinds of files without error? For example, only .log files get copied without worry. But I would like to copy also the files *.JPG, .zip, ...*. When I try with this kind of extension, the copy always gets an error. Thank you in advance for your answers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_CHAR 255

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    FILE * sourceFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");    
    FILE * destFile = fopen(argv[2], "w");    
    char line[MAX_CHAR];

    while (fgets(line, MAX_CHAR, sourceFile) != NULL)
    {
        fputs(line, destFile);
    }

    fclose(sourceFile);
    fclose(destFile);
}
```

Comment: And the error is... ?

Comment: You need to open the file in binary mode https://stackoverflow.com/a/5263102/7034621

Comment: *But I would like to copy also the files .JPG, .zip,*  Those aren't text files with lines....

Comment: Ah, you're opening binary files like text ones. You need the `rb`/`wb` flags.

Comment: @orhtej2 If OP is on Linux (or any other platform that doesn't differentiate text and binary streams) that won't matter.

Comment: These should be helpful: https://www.google.com/search?q=c+copy+binary+file+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that binary files typically have strings of bytes larger than 255 bytes before a null character.  Processing binary files as text simply does not work.  Do not use the string functions.